# RandomForest (RandomForestRegressor) returns weird predictions

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, random-forest, machine-learning-model

I wish to see how different algorithms perform when predicting stocks (using technical indicators as features). When modeling the randomForest (and looking at the graph) I get very bizarre results.

For the first 5500 or so data points the predictions are just a straight line, after that, it predicts the price rather well (probably overfitted but regardless).

[image]

(blue line is the test and red is the prediction)

I was wondering if anyone knows why it's behaving so strangely.

Comment: Does it seem like it is predicting the mean of your distribution for the first 5500 points. It seems like predictions are stagnant at 0.75 which is midway between 0.5 and 1.0.

Comment: Not really, the mean for the entire test dataset is 0.7993 and for the first 5500, it's higher than that.